# Getting python to respond to a specific key press

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to create a program that reads the text from a text file line by line. For the first 3 lines, the user simply needs to press enter to advance to the next line. For the fourth line, however, they need to press a specific key (the letter "u" in this case). I tried doing this using getch(), but for some reason pressing the "u" key does not generate any response. Here is the code:

```
from os import path
from msvcrt import getch
trial = 1
while trial < 5:
    p = path.join("C:/Users/Work/Desktop/Scripts/Cogex/item",  '%d.txt') % trial
    c_item = open(p) 
    print (c_item.readline())
    input()
    print (c_item.readline())
    input()
    print (c_item.readline())
    input()
    print (c_item.readline())
    if ord(getch()) == 85:
        print (c_item.readline())
        input()
trial += 1
```

I've also read about people using pygame or Tkinter, but I don't know if it is possible to use these without having the program use a graphical interface. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you pressing the Enter key after typing 'u'? The terminal you're using likely isn't going to provide the buffered input to the program until after the Enter key is pressed. There's no easy way to work around this without a GUI of sorts, as it's behavior of the terminal, and not your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I am pressing the enter key after typing 'u'. I might actually go for the GUI option...it's more straightforward in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is that input on most modern ttys is buffered - it is only sent to the application when the enter key is pressed. You can test this in C as well. If you create a GUI application that gets its' keyboard data directly from the OS then yes, you could do this. However, this would likely be more trouble than just asking the user to print the enter key after pressing u.
For example:

```
result = input()
if result == 'u':
    print(c_item.readline())
    input()
```

Answer (score 0):

`85` is the ordinal for capital `'U'`. For lowercase `'u'`, you need the ordinal `117`.

```
if ord(getch()) == 117:
```

You could also simply check whether the character is `b'u'`.

```
if getch() == b'u':
```

Or you could do a case-insensitive check for the ordinal:

```
if ord(getch()) in (85, 117):
```

Or for the string:

```
if getch().lower() == b'u'
```

You also need to move `trial += 1` into the loop:

```
if getch().lower() == b'u':
    print (c_item.readline())
    input()
trial += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion! However, this still doesn't solve the problem...I tried all the methods you described, and I still can't get python to respond to either an upper or lower case 'u'. If you have any other ideas I would love to hear them